# Create Event on Reservation Room Calendar - Google Apps API

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, resources

I have been trying to find information on how to create an event on a reservation room calendar, but have not been able to find the information I need.

```
var roomcalendar = 'company.org_12345621532439392d335552@resource.calendar.google.com';
var event = CalendarApp.roomcalendar.createEvent('Test Reservation', new Date('October 10, 2013 08:00:00 CST'), new Date('October 10, 2013 23:00:00 CST'));
```

I get an error saying TypeError: Cannot call method "createEvent" of undefined
I assume from what I have read in searching for answers that it is not finding the calendar. So I am assuming I am doing something wrong with how I am trying to access this reservation room.

I do have edit rights to the room calendar and have enabled rights for google scripts api to make changes as well. I just havent found documentation on how to edit other calendars so I am sure I am missing something simple but am not finding what I need in the API reference.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `roomcalendar` as a [calendar object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar?hl=fr-FR), from there you get the method `createEvent()`

in your code it would become :

```
  var roomcalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('company.xxx_32333138383233372d313638@resource.calendar.google.com');
  var event = roomcalendar.createEvent('Test Reservation', new Date('October 10, 2013 08:00:00 CST'), new Date('October 10, 2013 23:00:00 CST'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure why I wasn't finding something so basic in the documentation for the calendar API, but all the example I was finding were only about accessing your own calendar.

Comment: I provided a link to the appropriate doc. please consider accepting the answer. thanks